# Mean field calculation of the Critical dynamic exponent $z$

Tags: statistical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, critical-phenomena, mean-field-theory

In the prediction of the Kibble-Zurek-Mechanism for defects correlation length and relaxation time which are for 2D melting described by the KTHNY *(Kosterlitz-Thouless-Halperin-Nelson-Young theory, which is about the topological defect-mediated phase transition)*, there is the mean-field calculated value for dynamic critical exponent $z$ which says $z=2$ in that specific universality class, For instance, One can find it in Zurek and Campo's article, ([here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.1600)) they discuss the universality of phase transition dynamics, specifically in page 20.

If anybody knows a solid reference for the calculation I would greatly appreciate it if you let me know.

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.

Comment: Sure, It is Kosterlitz, Thouless, Halperin, Nelson, and Young theory for 2D melting, which is about the topological defect-mediated phase transition.

Comment: You need to edit that in to the question and if it's a paper or book, a reference would be expected.  Don't expect people here to help you without you making it easy for them to find material you reference.  People don't necessarily read comments.  Note that comments can be deleted by the system anytime, whereas questions and answers are persistent, hence the need to edit the question.

Comment: $z = 2$ is the typical value for dynamical exponents in mean-field theory unless you have a conserved quantity (e.g., dynamic Ising model with spin flips that preserve magnetization). The value comes from the free theory/Gaussian fixed point $\partial_t \phi - \nabla^2\phi$ being invariant under rescaling $x \rightarrow b x$ and $t \rightarrow b^z t$ (i.e., no field renormalization in mean-field). You'll find you need $z = 2$. I'm not familiar with this model but I expect that derivation is the basis for the claim.

Comment: @StephenG-HelpUkraine Thanks for the constructive comment I tried to edit the question to a better form while keeping it short.

Comment: @bbrink Sounds interesting, I will look deeper into this, thanks for the helpful comment.

Comment: @AlirezaValizadeh This review by Tauber covers non-equilibrium versions of classical phi^4 theory (with and without conserved 'magnetization'), including calculation of the dynamical exponent in and beyond mean-field theory: https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0511743 . Again, I am not sure if any differences in the KTHNY model require a different approach, but it may be instructive.